# Why PackageInfo always empty?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin for developing a project with a generic trunk and two side branches for android and UWP.

The project is an app built in C#.

For some reason the PackageInfo always comes back empty. How can that be if there are loads of apps installed on my test phone? Including the one I'm looking for?

Any help would be much appreciated since I need this for work and I'm stuck with this problem for a few weeks now.

If there's information missing for your understanding or a question similar to this already exists please let me know.

Thank you so much.

I'm trying to verify the presence of an app that my app calls through an intent. As a first step I'm trying to retrieve the PackageInfo for that purpose so that I can check for the package name inside it.